# After upgrading to Ventura 13.6.1 and Xcode 15.0.1 (15A507), takes forever to run in iPhone 15 Pro Simulator (black screen)

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, macos-ventura

I recently upgraded my iMac to Ventura 13.6.1 and also updated Xcode to version 15.0.1 (15A507). Thereafter, I could not successfully run a simple SwiftUI project called WeSplit (from hackingwithswift). It worked fine before the upgrade/update. Now all I see is the iPhone 15 Pro simulator showing a black screen while the top of the Xcode project window shows "Installing WeSplit to iPhone 15 Pro" (with a "2" next to it — not sure what that "2" means). The Preview window shows "Preview paused". So it just sits there like this for a LONG TIME without any clues on what it's doing in the background. No error messages popped up...yet. Any suggestions?